# Crear nueva columna con una media entre dos valores de dos columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

estoy aprendiendo Pandas y estoy atascado en uno de los ejercicios. Tengo un dataframe (el de la foto de abajo) y tengo que crear una nueva columna pero que cada fila tenga la media que tiene la columna Female y Male.

No tengo forma de lograrlo y no me salen más que errores así que no sé cómo hacer este caso. ¿Alguna pista?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que incluyas el codigo de lo que tienes hecho para poder ayudarte mejor.

De momento, viendo esa tabla solo te puedo ayudar creando yo el dataframe yo mismo y haciendo dicha media. Este es el codigo que te propongo:

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.DataFrame({"disciplina": ["disciplina1", "disciplina2", "disciplina3"], "col1": [12,13,14], "col2": [12,12,14]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({"media": []})
#df1["media"]= (df1["col1"] + df1["col2"]) / 2
df2["media"]= (df1["col1"] + df1["col2"]) / 2

print(df1)
```

En la primera linea, creo el DataFrame y en la segunda linea hago la media, que seria simplemente crear otra columna en la cual se almacene la media haciendo la suma de "col1" y "col2" y diviendola entre dos.

PD: Recuerda siempre subir el codigo de tu trabajo

Un saludo, espero poder ayudarte!

Comment: Me ha funcionado, pero el problema sería si quiero hacer la media de más columnas (si son muchas, no es eficiente sumar manualmente todas para hacer la división). En ese caso, ¿cómo sería? 

Respecto al código, no he subido nada porque es lo que tengo. El dataframe en sí tiene cientos de entradas.

Comment: Por cierto, si quisiera guardar el dataframe generado con la nueva columna con la media en otra variable para no alterar el dataframe original, ¿cómo sería? Porque de la manera habitual da error en este caso...

Comment: Buenas @MeN he editado la respuesta para guardar la informacion de la media en otro DataFrame, en cuanto a el problema de muchas columnas no se me ocurre una forma diferente de hacerlo. Existe una funcion en pandas llamada isnumeric() que comprueba que los datos de la columna del DataFrame sean numericos. Basandote en eso, deberas comprobar que los datos de tu columna sean numericos y despues hacer la media, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo de una manera "general" para todas las columnas. Siento no poder ayudarte. Un saludo